# Freelancer - taxes in India when working for a Spanish company

Tags: taxes, india, income, spain

I would be starting as a freelancer for an European company where the products will be promoted in the Indian market, hence would be traded from Europe to India. The same company has plans to start Indian operation after six months as their subsidiary however till that time they will pay me some fixed amount for sales and marketing including my office and travel expenses.

Could I know what is amount of taxes I have to pay as freelancer to the Indian government? European company expects me to submit invoice so that they could pay me directly. Is it advisable to open private firm so that I could apply for Import/export code, VAT registration, etc? Or as a Freelance can I import and sale the products without forming private firm?

Comment: Hope this is not one of the scams.

Answer (score 1):

> Could I know what is amount of taxes I have to pay as freelancer to Indian government ?

The tax is same as any individual [salaried or otherwise] has to pay.

> European company expects me to submit invoice so that they could pay me directly

Yes you can submit invoice as an individual.

> Is it advisable to open private firm so that I could apply form Import /export code , VAT registration etc ? Or as a Freelance can I import and sale the products without forming private firm ?

One can do this individually or via private firm. Consult a professional CA for specific advice as quite a bit would depend on what is getting imported and sold.